# Generating single exe InstallShield 2012 limited edtion in visual Studio 2012

Tags: installshield-le

I'm using InstallShield Wizard spring limited edition in Visual Studio 2012. I want to know how can I generate a SINGLE .EXE installer file in installshield, I'm now getting two ini files, a cab file, an msi file and an exe file.

Thank You

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Right click on solution and choose "Configuration Manager...". Than set "SingleImage" configuration option against the setup project.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else reading this that has multiple releases and no 'SingleImage' configuration.

Go into Releases, select the Release(s) and Set 'Compression' to 'Compressed' and this will compress the release into a single exe